# Возможно ли при помощи try-with-resources закрыть все элементы списка?

Tags: java, try-catch

Генерируется список / массив, состоящий из объектов `AutoCloseable`. Возможно ли закрыть все элементы списка при помощи **try-with-resources**?

Потому что сейчас мне приходится писать функциональность **try-with-resources** руками, что меня не устраивает:

```
Set<AutoCloseable> autoCloseableResources = new HashSet<>();
try {
    // генерируем здесь AutoCloseable элементы и добавляем их в множество autoCloseableResources
} catch (Throwable var11) {
    var2 = var11;
    throw var11;
} finally {
    autoCloseableResources
        .forEach(resource -> {
            if (resource != null) {
            if (var2 != null) {
                try {
                    resource.close();
                } catch (Throwable var10) {
                    var2.addSuppressed(var10);
                }
            } else {
                resource.close();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Возможно ли каким-либо образом автоматически закрыть все элементы списка `autoCloseableResources` с использованием **try-with-resources**?

Comment: "и он меня не устраивает" - ??

Comment: @Igor он меня не устраивает, потому что я не хочу писать бойлерплейт руками. Вопрос же в конце написан

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напишите свой

```
class MyCloseableSet extends Set<AutoCloseable> implements AutoCloseable {
  ...
```

Comment: Что-то не додумался)

Answer (score 0):

Автоматически можно, только надо использовать один ресурс в try-with-resources. Этот ресурс должен имплементить [`AutoClosable` интерфейс](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), а бойлерплейт код можно перенести в имплементацию.